# How to fill in area of geom_point in proportion to value? (e.g. Harvey balls)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to create geom_points whose area is filled in according to a proportion. Something like Harvey balls, although Harvey balls usually only map 0% 25% 50% 75% and 100% whereas in this case the fill could be anything from 0 to 100% e.g.

[image]

The geom_point doesn't need to be a circle, it could be a bar whose area fills up in proportion to the frac as well. So long as the area fill is proportional to fraction it'll work fine. e.g.

[image]

Reproducible data

```
library(tidyverse)  

df <- 
    tibble(
      x = c(1:5),
      y = c(5:1),
      yes = c(1, 14, 10, 42, 53),
      total = c(11, 21, 25, 50, 100),
      frac = yes/total)
    
df %>% 
  ggplot(
    aes(
      x = x,
      y = y)) + 
  geom_point(
    fill = "#000000",
    size = 7.5)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at `geom_scatterpie`:

```r
library(scatterpie)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_scatterpie(data = df, cols = c("frac", "opp_frac"), 
                  size = 1, pie_scale = 3) + 
  coord_equal()
```

---

data

```r
df <- 
  tibble(
    x = c(1:5),
    y = c(5:1),
    yes = c(1, 14, 10, 42, 53),
    total = c(11, 21, 25, 50, 100),
    frac = yes/total, 
    opp_frac = 1 - frac)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice one, I updated my graph with your option tip about 'size' & 'pie_scale'

Answer (score 2):

Library `scatterpie` allows to display such plot.
You must have one variable by proportion you want to display, here: `fracPos` and `fracNeg`.

```
### Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)  
library(scatterpie)
library(ggthemes)

### Data-management
df <- 
  tibble(
    x = c(1:5),
    y = c(5:1),
    yes = c(1, 14, 10, 42, 53),
    total = c(11, 21, 25, 50, 100),
    fracPos = yes/total,
    fracNeg = 1- yes/total)

### Plot proportions
ggplot() +
  geom_scatterpie(data=df, aes(x=x, y=y), 
                  cols = c("fracPos", "fracNeg"), color="white", 
                  size = 1, pie_scale = 3) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values=c("orange", "black")) + 
  theme_hc() + 
  theme(legend.position="none")
```

[image]

Updated with Maël tips.