# Is there an R dot type or coloring aesthetic to have the same dot with two different colors?

Tags: r

I sometimes struggle with graphs were there there is a cathegorical variable which can be understood as ordinal and is to be plotted with different colors.
Usually, different colors (v.gr. red, blue, green...) are just used, but I would like to use for instance, white, half-white-half-grey, grey, half-grey-half-black, black, where the ordering of the variable would be more apparent.

I have found this roundabout to create half circles, and this could be used to create dots with two colors
([how to draw two half circles in ggplot in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47493197/how-to-draw-two-half-circles-in-ggplot-in-r)
), but I wonder if there is in R a pch type or similar to do the job.

Imagine I want to plot this data, grouped with a cathegorical variable which has an order (alphabetical):

```
#library(ggplot2)

mydata1 <- data.frame("var1" = sample(c(1:12), 12),
                  "var2" = sample(c(1:12), 12),
                  "group" = letters[1:3]) # three groups
```

I can use grayscale so its order is apparent, and this works fine:

```
ggplot(data = mydata1, aes(var1, var2, color = group)) + 
geom_point() + 
scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 1)
```

If instead of 3 groups I had 4, it still works, as lightgray and darkgray can be distinguished:

```
mydata2 <- data.frame("var1" = sample(c(1:12), 12),
                      "var2" = sample(c(1:12), 12),
                      "group" = letters[1:4]) # four groups
ggplot(data = mydata2, aes(var1, var2, color = group)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 1)
```

But if I had 5 or more groups, it stops working:

```
mydata3 <- data.frame("var1" = sample(c(1:10), 10),
           "var2" = sample(c(1:10), 10),
           "group" = letters[1:5]) # five groups
ggplot(data = mydata3, aes(var1, var2, color = group)) + geom_point() + 
  scale_color_grey(start = 0, end = 1)
```

Usually colors are used, but the ordered nature is not apparent.
If it existed an aesthetic to color points by halfs, it would allow to extend the use of the grayscale.

Comment: If you look at the `?pch` help page or do an image search for "r pch" you will see all the avaliable built-in options. There are 25 of them. Numbers 21-25 allow for different stroke and fill colors, but there is nothing like the "half and half" you describe.

Comment: Sounds like a variation on `Harvey Balls` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harvey_balls . Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/22225086/10276092 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/73369993/10276092

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses two sets of unicode geometric shapes, double-exposed.

Using the great `getPch()` function by @lukeA from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22226643/10276092

And creating a reverse `getPchRev()`

```
install.packages("extrafont")
library(extrafont)
loadfonts()
getPch <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(x) {
    switch(as.character(x), 
           "0"=-9675,
           "25"=-9684,
           "50"=-9682,
           "75"=-9685,
           "100"=-9679
    )})
}

getPchRev <- function(x) {
  sapply(x, function(x) {
    switch(as.character(x), 
           "100"=-9675,
           "75"=-9684,
           "50"=-9683, ##reverse 50%
           "25"=-9685,
           "0"=-9679
    )})
}

df<-data.frame(x=1:10,
               y=1:10,
               value=50,
               a=1:10,
               b=10:1)

library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=a), shape=getPch(df$value), size=5) +   
  geom_point(aes(color=b), shape=getPchRev(df$value), size=5) + 
  scale_color_viridis_c()
```

[image]